# Bottomnavigation: graphical glitch of the button

Tags: java, android

I am using `BottomNavigation` for my layout and after I press one button and change the page, the button looks as if I am still pressing it. It helps me if someone can give me a solution.

XML file

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>
```

The glitch:

[image: Mainactivity glitch]

Comment: what does it mean "*look as i am still pressing it*"?

Comment: try changing your colorAccent in the colors to #FFFFFF and let us see the result

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I changed the background to  #FFFFFF. It all solved. For those who couldn't understand my "look as i am still pressing it"? expression. It means that the button looked as I was still pressing it, despite the fact that I let go my fingers from the button.